# Displaying Date and Time in user's device format and language

Tags: java, android, datetime, format, simpledateformat

I need to display date and time in user's device settings format (with text "at"). For example:

On US Device it can be: **November 2, 2018 at 5:28:20 PM**

On Indian: **2 November 2018 at 17:28:20**

On Russian: **2 ноября 2018 в 17:28:20**

It should depend on user device preferences and language. Also it should contain seconds. It should look like date and time at user reviews on Google Play console.

Could you please help how to implement it?

p.s. I store datetime information in sqlite and read like this:

```
String milliseconds = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("datetime"));    
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    
try {
    date = format.parse(milliseconds);
    //But how to format this date now?
    //I found the following two functions:
    Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(context);
    Format timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
    String finalDateTime = dateFormat.format(date) + " at " + timeFormat.format(date); 
    //But here time without seconds. How to add seconds?
}
```

Also, maybe there is a more correct way to read it from the database? But it is a second matter.

Comment: what is your min api?

Comment: Arahasya, what is your suggestion? For old devices I can make some universal date time format. It is not a problem. (my min api 14)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: What would be your desired result for Danish? Danish doesn’t use any preposition before the time of day. What I am trying to point out is that I think you’re trying to do something that doesn’t make sense in all locales.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not formatting the date using the device its locale. From the documentation use the:

```
public SimpleDateFormat (String pattern, Locale locale)
```

> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default date format symbols for the given locale.

So something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat result = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
format.format(date);

Date date = new Date(milliseconds);

try {
    Locale locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else {
        locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM hh:mm:ss", locale);
    String formatedDate = format.format(new Date());
}
```

If you want to format your date differently, check this documentation page: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Too complicated for me. I can't find a solution there.

Comment: This code just displays dates like this: 2018-11-02 17:32:17 But I need device settings format. Please see my post (different dates).

Comment: If you want a different format change the value on your `SimpleDateFormat`. Use this one: dd MMMM hh:mm:ss. Check the table in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I need to use user device date and time format (and on different languages).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
     Locale locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else {
        locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
    }

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM hh:mm:ss",locale);
    String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date  "+datetime);
```

Comment: Every time day will be before month though. If you specifically want month before day you will have to use switch case according to locale which will be complicated